# How do I organize this list of polygons in java so that they are easy to work with?

Tags: java, organization, code-organization, fractals, chaos

My question involves address spaces of fractals that can be generated using the chaos game. These address spaces are simply transformations of a main shape with relation to one-another.

[image]

In the image [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/Sierpinski.gif), you can see that there is a triangle labeled "2". Triangles "21", "22", and "23" are related to triangle 2 because you must transform it to get these smaller child triangles.

This is what I want to do..... given the following parameters:

- Int s: The number of sides in the original shape
- Int d: The depth down the tree of shapes we want (in the image, d=2 because we generate the 3 smaller triangles of a main triangle, and then generate their children as well)
- Polygon p: The original shape which we intend to make children from

... I would like to take those parameters and start iterating down each depth level with a counter "i". You can check that at level i, there are s^d shapes that are needed. Each of these shapes will depend on a poly that is in the level above, so how do I store these in some way where I can create lots of levels of depth in a way that makes simple sense, and can also use for loops or some other efficient and simple way? My best hope is that at each depth level i can access parents for the triangles I want to create at this level. I also want to reference the shapes later, either by direct name since this is a unique id, or some other simple way.

My original plan was to somehow work with the name for each shape (the labels seen in the image). I could have a massive array of shapes somehow but only populate indexes "1", "2", "3", "11", "12", "13", "21", "22", etc. However this seems not only messy and inefficient, but seems nonsensical as i would have to work at a way to get these permutations of 1, 2, and 3 in a way i can handle. There must be a better way!

In case it helps, I have provided my source code:

```
package chaosaddresses;

import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.awt.Polygon;

public class AddressManager
{
public Address originalPoly;
public ArrayList<Address>[] array;
public int depth;
public int sides;


public AddressManager(int d, int s, Address a)
{
    depth = d;
    sides = s;
    originalPoly = a;
    initArray();
}

private void initArray()
{
    //loop through each depth and get all needed polygons
    //number of polys at each depth is s^d.
    for (int i=1; i <= depth; i++)
    {
        int numPolys = (int)Math.pow(sides,i);
        int numParentPolys = array[i-1].size();
        ArrayList<Address> thisLevel = new ArrayList<>();

        //iterate parent polys and have each generate their children
        for (int j= 0; j < numParentPolys; j++)
        {
            Address[] babies = array[i-1].get(j).makeChildren();

            //add babies to current level
            for (int k=0; k < babies.length; k++)
            {
                thisLevel.add(babies[k]);
            }
        }
        array[i] = thisLevel;
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fractals lend themselves to recursion, since their calculation is recursive by nature. One way to organize this is to have each level hold a reference to the instances of the next level, giving you a tree of levels, each which have recursively created their children.

---

**Edit**
For example, something along this order:

```
public class Sierpinski {
   public static int MAX_LEVEL = 6;
   private int level;
   private Point2D[] points = new Point2D[3];
   private Sierpinski[] childTriangles = null;

   private Sierpinski(int level, Point2D[] points) {
      this.level = level;
      this.points = points;

      if (level < MAX_LEVEL) {
         childTriangles = createChildren();
      }
   }

   public int getLevel() {
      return level;
   }

   public Point2D[] getPoints() {
      return points;
   }

   private Sierpinski[] createChildren() {
      // TODO finish method....
   }

   public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
      // TODO finish method:
      // ....  draw this triangle

      if (childTriangles != null) {
         for (Sierpinski childTriangle : childTriangles) {
            childTriangle.draw(g2);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: A reasonable thought.... I will give some time into thinking about this type of organization. I think i would need another object type though besides my manager class, so that it could hold references to children or something.... *thinking wheel starts rotating* ....

Comment: I changed my code to reflect this sort of idea. would this type of thing work, assuming i have an "Address" class with methods that work properly?

Comment: Okay im sorry but im having issues picturing how this would work. If i had "Sierpinski a", would i refer to its children as a.childTriangles[0] a.childTriangles[1] etc? and something two layers from a would be a.childTriangles[1].childTriangles[1] ?